# MAX NOT WORKING IN SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I want the latest record to be retrieved by the following query....
but max is not working in the below query. All the rows are getting retrieved instead of the latest one

```
 SELECT SV.SEGMENT1 TARGETED_INCENTIVE,
                         SIT.ANALYSIS_CRITERIA_ID,
                         SIT.OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER,
                         ST.ID_FLEX_NUM,
                         SIT.DATE_FROM,
                         SIT.DATE_TO,
                         MAX (SIT.PERSON_ANALYSIS_ID)

                    FROM FND_ID_FLEX_STRUCTURES_TL STTL,
                         FND_ID_FLEX_STRUCTURES ST,
                         PER_PERSON_ANALYSES SIT,
                         PER_ANALYSIS_CRITERIA SV
                   WHERE     1 = 1
                         AND (STTL.ID_FLEX_STRUCTURE_NAME) LIKE
                                ('%%Tare%')
                         AND STTL.LANGUAGE = USERENV ('LANG')
                         AND ST.ID_FLEX_CODE = STTL.ID_FLEX_CODE
                         AND ST.ID_FLEX_NUM = STTL.ID_FLEX_NUM
                         AND ST.ID_FLEX_NUM = SIT.ID_FLEX_NUM
                         AND ST.ID_FLEX_NUM = SV.ID_FLEX_NUM
                         AND TO_DATE (SIT.DATE_TO) IS NULL
                         AND SIT.ANALYSIS_CRITERIA_ID = SV.ANALYSIS_CRITERIA_ID
                         AND SIT.PERSON_ID = (SELECT PERSON_ID
                                                FROM abc
                                               WHERE ID = :AIN)
                GROUP BY SV.SEGMENT1,
                         SIT.ANALYSIS_CRITERIA_ID,
                         STTL.ID_FLEX_STRUCTURE_NAME,
                         SIT.OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER,
                         ST.ID_FLEX_NUM,
                         SIT.DATE_FROM,
                         SIT.DATE_TO;
```

Can anyone guide ?

Comment: It will retrive all rows with respect to group by columns. Add some sample data and the expected data.

Comment: ok.. but when i am using group by on unique columns then it is giving error ...

Comment: Maybe simplify the problem a little

Comment: Please describe what "not working" means.

Comment: @GordonLinoff- It is returning all the rows... instead of the max one

Comment: What in the query logic is suggesting that only the "max one" should be returned?  The is going to return one row for each combination of the `group by` expressions, along with the maximum of of the column specified.  Without sample data and desired results, there is no way to tell what is "wrong".  The query does what the query does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not what `MAX()` does. `MAX()` is an aggregate function (though it can be used as a window [analytic] function), so when you get the `MAX()` of a particular column grouped by other columns, you will get distinct combinations of values for all those other columns.

I think you might want something like this:

```
SELECT targeted_incentive, analysis_criteria_id
     , object_version_number, id_flex_num, date_from
     , date_to, person_analysis_id
  FROM (
    SELECT sv.segment1 AS targeted_incentive
         , sit.analysis_criteria_id
         , sit.object_version_number
         , st.id_flex_num
         , sit.date_from
         , sit.date_to
         , sit.person_analysis_id
         , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY sit.person_analysis_id DESC ) rn
      FROM fnd_id_flex_structures_tl sttl
         , fnd_id_flex_structures st
         , per_person_analyses sit
         , per_analysis_criteria sv
     WHERE sttl.id_flex_structure_name LIKE '%Tare%'
       AND sttl.language = USERENV('LANG')
       AND st.id_flex_code = sttl.id_flex_code
       AND st.id_flex_num = sttl.id_flex_num
       AND st.id_flex_num = sit.id_flex_num
       AND st.id_flex_num = sv.id_flex_num
       AND sit.date_to IS NULL
       AND sit.analysis_criteria_id = sv.analysis_criteria_id
       AND sit.person_id = ( SELECT person_id FROM abc
                              WHERE id = :AIN )
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

The `RANK()` window function will return the rank of each row ordered by the value of `person_analysis_id` in descending order. To get the maximum value, simply filter for rank = 1. Note that this will return more than one row in case of ties. If you want only one row, use `ROW_NUMBER()` in place of `RANK()`.

Also note that I cleaned up the query a bit. You certainly don't need to use two `%` wildcards in a row in a `LIKE`, for example. You also definitely don't need the `WHERE 1=1` condition.